# Cannot set property 'someProperty' of undefined - Angular Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a class Article which has property of type Image and looks like this:

```
export class Article {
   public image:Image;
   public images: Image[]; 
}
```

If I comment `this.article.image = new Image();` like this:

```
constructor()
{
    this.article = new Article();
    //this.article.image = new Image();
}
```

And If I try to use an this.image later in code, like:

```
 this.article.image.fileName = file.name;
```

I will get following error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property '..' of undefined

But I realized in case when I try to add something to an array for example:

```
this.article.images.push(something);
```

**I am not getting error!** And I'm wondering why I don't get error when I use array (even if I did not said `this.article.images = new Images[]..` , and why I get error when I'm using simple object/not array..

Comment: What is image???can you show me the image class?

Comment: `this.article.image` is `undefined`, You havent assigned any value to it, You should create new `Image` `object` and assign it to `this.article.image` before setting file name like this ->  `this.article.image.fileName = file.name;`

Answer (score 2):

I guess the `..` in your error code means `fileName`.

You actually explained the error yourself.

> `If I comment this.article.image = new Image();`

You removed the creation of your image, thus, `this.article.image` is undefined.

So by using `this.article.image.fileName`, you are trying to access the property `fileName` of `undefined`.

However, for the property `images`, the method `.push()` already exists because it's a method defined by `Array`, which is known thanks to the declaration :

```
public images: Image[];
```

Comment: To add to this, I think `images` works fine because of the declaration `Image[]; `.

Comment: I edited my answer to add the second part of the explanation